# How to identify number of connections to a Postgres Database (heroku)?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to identify the number of connections to a postgres database. This is in context of the connection limit on heroku-postgres for dev and hobby plans, which is limited to 20. I have a python django application using the database. I want to understand what constitute a connection. Will each instance of an user using the application count as one connection ? Or The connection from the application to the database is counted as one.

To figure this out I tried the following.

1. Opened multiple instances of the application from different clients (3 separate machines).
2. Connected to the database using an online Adminer tool(https://adminer.cs50.net/)
3. Connected to the database using pgAdmin installed in my local system.
4. Created and ran dataclips (query reports) on the database from heroku.
5. Ran the following query from adminer and pgadmin to observe the number of records:

`select * from pg_stat_activity where datname ='db_name';`

Initial it seemed there was a new record for each for the instance of the application I opened and 1 record for the adminer instance. After some time the query from adminer was showing 6 records (2 connections for adminer, 2 for the pgadmin and 2 for the web-app).

Unfortunately I am still not sure if each instance of users using my web application would be counted as a connection or will all connections to the database from the web app be counted as one ?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Using PostgreSQL  parameters to log connections and disconnections (with right `log_line_prefix` parameter to have client information) should help:

> log_connections (boolean)
>
> Causes each attempted connection to the server to be logged, as well as successful completion of client authentication. Only
>   superusers can change this parameter at session start, and it cannot
>   be changed at all within a session. The default is off.
>
> log_disconnections (boolean)
>
> Causes session terminations to be logged. The log output provides information similar to log_connections, plus the duration of the
>   session. Only superusers can change this parameter at session start,
>   and it cannot be changed at all within a session. The default is off.

Comment: Thanks @pifor , I will try these. Do you know from your experience the answer to this : if each instance of users using my web application would be counted as a connection or will all connections to the database from the web app be counted as one ?

Comment: In general with a connection pool, you should have many connections to the web app mapped to a limited number of database connections that use a single user in the database (but note I am only db specialist not a app. server specialist and I never worked with Heroku).

Comment: that makes sense. Unfortunately I don't have the access to change these, but helpful tip for future.